# please explain code of anagram ,i can't understand counter array ,every value already is 0

Tags: c++, anagram

```
bool isAnagram(string c, string d){
    if(c.length()!=d.length())
        return false;
    int count[256]={0};
    for(int i=0;i<c.length();i++){
        count[c[i]]++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<d.length();i++){
        count[d[i]]--;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<c.length();i++)
        if(count[c[i]]!=0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

please explain code of anagram ,i can't understand counter array ,every value already is 0 ,so every index must be included,is it storing asci value wise

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into your question instead of linking an image. This makes your question accessible and easier to search.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418 so please provide a [mre].

Comment: Also please describe how you, as a human, can tell that two words are anagrams of each other. How could you find that out? Try especially to describe a way based on counting letters.

Comment: Yes it's storing values 'ASCII wise'. It's counting all the letters in `c` and subtracting the counts of all the letters in `d`. If at the end of that everything is zero then the two words are anagrams.

Comment: I think you will understand if you run through the code in your head, first with two anagrams and then with two non-anagrams. If you don't know how to do that, this is an excellent opportunity for practicing it.

Comment: This "every value already is 0" seems to especially confuse you. Why? Is there a typo and you meant e.g. "every value always is 0"? Please elaborate what is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar question but this illustrates the use of counter arrays:

```
    int makeAnagram(string a, string b) {
    vector<int> freq(26,0);

    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++) freq[a[i] - 'a']++;
    for(int j=0;j<b.length();j++) freq[b[j] - 'a']--;

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++) sum += abs(freq[i]);
    
    return sum;
}
```

A counter array is used to "count" values (I named it freq for frequency). Here `freq[0]` is the same as `the frequency/count of the char 'a'` because `'a' - 'a' = 0`. This is also how you can cope with the ascii conversion and why my freq vector is of size 26.

Comment: What is the difference between this code and the one shown by OP? I get the impression they are very similar. Also OP does not seem to ask for a (different) solution and instead wants an explanation of the shown one. All in all my impression is that you do not answer the question.

Comment: I explain the concept of counter array, OP asks this?

Comment: yes ,your code sorts the array alphabetically with frequencies  , lik a at 0  b at1  and c=99-97  at 3   and finally sums all the frequency